Unable to auto-import libraries in python and jupyter notebook files
I cannot for the life of me fathom why VS code is not displaying import suggestions in a popup or auto-importing missing packages as it should be doing.
VSCode version: 1.95.3
Pylance version: v2024.11.3
The venv is managed by poetry and it's configured correctly, when I correct the import paths manually, the python code or notebook code runs without issues.
In python files, I get no suggestions:

In jupyter notebooks, I get no suggestions either.



it seems somehow related to the the visibility of the venv, builtins such as 'pprint' are auto imported correctly, while fastai's ImageClassifierCleaner is not. But the venv is correct as the import in Pycharm is totally functional, it's just vscode not finding those symbols?

Again, the libs are installled, when the path is added by hand, I can navigate 3rd party libs, the notebook runs fine, etc.
